# Python Creating recursive function / loop for a function that Input/output Lists

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to simulate a biological gene network by updating the probabilities of the genes for each time step in Python. Then, the results for each time step will be plotted. I can do it by coping and pasting over and over again, but it is not ideal once the time steps becomes larger than 10. Here are what I have exactly done so far.

```
Pgt1, Pkr1, Pkni1, Phb1 = test.simUpdateFun(PgtI, PkrI, PkniI, PhbI)
Pgt2, Pkr2, Pkni2, Phb2 = test.simUpdateFun(Pgt1, Pkr1, Pkni1, Phb1)
Pgt3, Pkr3, Pkni3, Phb3 = test.simUpdateFun(Pgt2, Pkr2, Pkni2, Phb2)
Pgt4, Pkr4, Pkni4, Phb4 = test.simUpdateFun(Pgt3, Pkr3, Pkni3, Phb3)
Pgt5, Pkr5, Pkni5, Phb5 = test.simUpdateFun(Pgt4, Pkr4, Pkni4, Phb4)

data.dataPlot(PgtI, PkrI, PkniI, PhbI)
data.dataPlot(Pgt1, Pkr1, Pkni1, Phb1)
data.dataPlot(Pgt2, Pkr2, Pkni2, Phb2)
data.dataPlot(Pgt3, Pkr3, Pkni3, Phb3)
data.dataPlot(Pgt4, Pkr4, Pkni4, Phb4)
data.dataPlot(Pgt5, Pkr5, Pkni5, Phb5)
```

simUpdateFun is a function I wrote within a class to implement the genes' interaction and update the probabilities. Also, the data structure for each variable is a list that contain around 20 data points.

At first I am thinking about doing a recursion function for the update. Unfortunately, my knowledge in Python is rather limited (self-taught during a summer), and all I know of recursion function in Python are simple cases such as factorial function and Fibonacci sequences. The biggest problem for me is not being able to go around writing a loop or even the recursive function given the input and output for the simUpdateFun are lists.

The simUpdateFun is as follow:

```
def simUpdateFun(self, PgtPre, PkrPre, PkniPre, PhbPre):
    """A function to update the gap gene probabilities based on the mutual repression relationship from the previous ones"""
    PgtS = [] 
    PkrS = []
    PkniS = []
    PhbS = []
    #PgtS = list(i for i in PgtPre)
    # implement the mutual strong repression interaction
    for i in range(self.xlen):
        PgtS.append(1-PkrPre[i])
        PkrS.append(1-PgtPre[i])
        PkniS.append(1-PhbPre[i])
        PhbS.append(1-PkniPre[i])

    # implementation of the weak overlapping repression interaction
    PgtR = []
    PkrR = []
    PkniR = []
    PhbR = []

    x = len(PgtPre)
    P1 = 0
    P2 = int(x/4 )
    P3 = int(x * 2/4 )
    P4 = int(x * 3/4 )
    P5 = int(x )

    # first calculate the repressor probability function for the gap genes
    for i in PgtPre:
        PgtR.append(self.repressor(i, 1))
    for i in PkrPre:
        PkrR.append(self.repressor(i, 1))
    for i in PkniPre:
        PkniR.append(self.repressor(i,1))
    for i in PhbPre:
        PhbR.append(self.repressor(i, 1))

    # implement the interactions of weak repression of overlapping genes
    # Try to avoid alternating the initial condition values by copy a new set of list objects.

    PgtW = list(i for i in PgtPre) # using generator expression simplified the codes and also minimize # of lines
    PkrW = list(i for i in PkrPre)
    PkniW = list(i for i in PkniPre)
    PhbW= list(i for i in PhbPre)

    for i in range(P4, P5): # qudrant 4 regulation
        PgtW[i] = PgtPre[i] * PhbR[i]
    for i in range(P3, P4): # qudrant 3 regulation
        PkniW[i] = PkniPre[i] * PgtR[i]

    for i in range(P2, P3): # qudrant 2 regulation
        PkrW[i] = PkrPre[i] * PkniR[i]

    for i in range(P1, P2): # qudrant 1 regulation
        PhbW[i] = PhbPre[i] * PkrR[i]
        PkrW[i] = PkrPre[i] * PhbR[i]

    # determinate the final probabilites of the two effects by multiplying since they take place simultatesily.

    Pgtf = []
    Pkrf = []
    Pknif = []
    Phbf = []
    for i in range(len(PgtPre)):
        Pgtf.append(PgtS[i] * PgtW[i])
        Pkrf.append(PkrS[i] * PkrW[i])
        Pknif.append(PkniS[i] * PkniW[i])
        Phbf.append(PhbS[i] * PhbW[i])

    return(Pgtf, Pkrf, Pknif, Phbf)
```

The function basically takes in a sets of list data which are probability values, and outputs the updated version of the lists.